# Переменная SetTimeout Jquery

Tags: jquery

Каким образом можно задать **переменную** в 1400 миллисекунд для **setTimeout** и вызвать ее а не прописывать каждый раз для разных функций setTimeout = 1400.

**Пример:**

```js
$('.modal-icon').click(function(){
$('#block').addClass('out');
setTimeout(function() {
$('body').css("overflow", "visible");
}, 1400);
});


$('.modal-icon').click(function(){
$('#block-2').addClass('clock');
setTimeout(function(){
$('body').css("overflow", "auto");
},1400);
});


$('.modal-icon').click(function(){
$('#block-3').addClass('fire');
setTimeout(function(){
$('body').css("display", "none");
},1400);
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что касается вопроса

```js
let to1400 = f => setTimeout(f, 1400);

$('.modal-icon').click(function(){
  $('#block').addClass('out');
  to1400( () => $('body').css("overflow", "visible") )
});


$('.modal-icon').click(function(){
  $('#block-2').addClass('clock');
  to1400( () => $('body').css("overflow", "auto") )
});


$('.modal-icon').click(function(){
  $('#block-3').addClass('fire');
  to1400( () => $('body').css("display", "none") )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

что касается подсократить приведенный участок кода:

```js
let action = (b, c, p, v) => $(b).addClass(c) && setTimeout(() => $('body').css(p, v), 1400)
let iconClick = f => $('.modal-icon').click(f);
iconClick(() => action('#block', 'out', "overflow", "visible"))
iconClick(() => action('#block-2', 'clock', "overflow", "auto"))
iconClick(() => action('#block-3', 'fire', "display", "none"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Да вы просто прям какой-то волшебник)))                                                                                      Благодарю вас)))                                                                                                                                  Как я понимаю вы сократили код на чистом javascript?   Сокращенный код это массив?

Comment: да это чистый js

Comment: Извините меня, пожалуйста. Если вам не трудно, то не могли бы вы подсказать как еще можно сократить код jquery под javascript.    Код внизу)))

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/JqvBMv

Comment: А это вы уже сократили на jquery)? Только последние две строки были написаны на javascript)?

Comment: я не трогал ваш код, только общую часть выделил

Comment: Если не секрет, то скажите пожалуйста сколько годов вы потратили на обучение, чтобы достигнуть такого уровня)))

Comment: Бог его знает, но я еще помню свой фидо-нет адрес =)

Comment: Ну примерно 10 лет? 5 лет?

Comment: за 5 можно очень не кисло поднатаскаться, лично я разработчиком работаю с 2005 примерно года, но время но этого периода тоже было связано с it, правда 20 лет назад все было мягко говоря не так как сейчас, это я к тому что я не перестаю изучать новые технологии - это непрерывный процесс

Comment: Вы разрабатываете в основном на javascript)?

Comment: всего по немножку, java, javascript, графика компьютерная

Comment: А говорят, что лучшие разработчики это самоучки. Это правда)?

Comment: на этот вопрос нельзя дать однозначный ответ, я больше самоучка, т.к. у меня нет профильного образования, я учился больше на разработчика железа и программирование у нас было очень сбоку

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.image3D-1').click(function(){
var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
$('#block-modal').removeAttr('class').addClass(buttonId);
$('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
})

$('.image3D-2').click(function(){
var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
$('#block-modal-2').removeAttr('class').addClass(buttonId);
$('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
})
```